# I need custom php file and upload to magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

example myconnect.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=meigee", $username, $password);
    //set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
echo "<br>";
echo "PHP on Magento";
?>
```

how to upload file mycon.php?
Magento1.9.4.3

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a shell script in order to leverage the "Magento way" of coding

You may follow this tutorial

https://inchoo.net/magento/php-shell-scripts-for-magento/

Using shell scripts you would be able to use Magento classes inside of your custom shell PHP script.